# Cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by "libjninice.so

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have below error when starting my android app:

```
dlopen failed: Cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by  libjninice.so
```

I Searched on internet for the solution and I got to know that if I change my Android-platform to 19 and my Toolchain-version to 4.8 ,it will work. But in my case I need some workaround for this, becauase I have to make it work for android-platform 21 .

PS- I have built all my libraries using Android-ndk r10e Toolchain-version-4.9 and Android-platform=21

Comment: if you compile your lib for android-platform=19, it will work on Android 21+ devices too.

Comment: @ph0b- I am trying doing the same now,but getting struck with the dependencies because earlier everything was done for 21and now i have to start again using platform 19

Comment: what is *everything* ? your Java can be targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion 21+ while your native code is APP_PLATFORM:=android-19. If you aren't using new NDK APIs introduced with Lollipop, you shouldn't face any issue.

Comment: @ph0b Hi I compiled my libraries for android-platform=19 but my application is getting crashed and its showing  the following error:-                  Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x4e746567

Comment: It's a runtime error coming from your lib, I doubt it has anything to do with platform versions. Look at the full backtrace inside your logcat to determine where it exactly comes from.

Comment: @ph0b Great info. I just ran into the same error regarding rand(). Good to know that I can set the NDK to API 19 while the Java has target SDK of 22.

Comment: Very helpful! Running into this issue in production and didn't know about the possibility of API "mismatch" between NDK and Java SDK.